# undefined behaviour on dynamic allocated arrays (segmentation fault)

Tags: c, dynamic, segmentation-fault, undefined, heap-memory

This program calculates Fibonacci series of the form: t1, t2, t3 = t1 + t^2, t4 = t2+t3^2 ...

It takes three inputs t1, t2 and nth number in the series you want to calculate.

Since the numbers increase exponentially, i used arrays to display and perform manipulations on large numbers.

## PROBLEM:

I'm stuck with some weird error on:

```
bsquare[j] = *b[j]
```

use inputs 0 1 8 to recreate the error, it works fine for inputs upto 7. also i tried debugging using gdb, but the debugger shows that memory is accessible when i use p **b@50 and bn also seems to be valid. Is there some undefined behaviour i'm missing out on?

### Code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int carry = 0;
int fibo( int **a, int **b, int **c, int n);
void sum(int *a, int *b, int *c, int *an, int *bn, int *cn);
void sqr(int *b, int *bn);
int main()
{   

    int *a, *b, *c;
    int t1, t2, n, i, bn;

    scanf("%d%d%d",&t1, &t2,&n);

    a = (int * ) calloc(100, sizeof(int));
    b = (int * ) calloc(100, sizeof(int));
    c = (int * ) calloc(100, sizeof(int));
    a[0] = t1; b[0] = t2;

    bn = fibo(&a,&b,&c,n);

    printf("\nNumber is: ");
    for(i = bn-1; i>=0; i--)
    printf("%d",b[i]);

    free(a);free(b);free(c);
    return 0;
}
void sqr(int *b, int *bn)
{   int c[50] = {0};
    int i , j ,k = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < *bn; i++)
    {    k = i;
        carry = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < *bn ;j++)
        {
            temp = c[k] + b[i] * b[j] + carry;
            if(temp>9)
            {
                carry = temp / 10;
                c[k] = temp % 10;

            }
            else
            {
                c[k] =  temp;
                carry = 0;
            }
            k++;
        }
        if(carry !=0)
        {c[k++] = carry;
        }

    }

    for(i = 0; i<k; i++)
    {   
        b[i] = c[i];

    }

    *bn = k;



}

void sum(int *a, int *b, int *c, int *an, int *bn, int *cn)
{

    int i=0 , j ,k = 0;
    int *temp1;
    int temp = 0;
    for(j=0; j<*cn; j++)
     c[j] = 0;
            *cn = 0;
     carry = 0;
    for(; i < *bn && i < *an; i++)
    {   
        temp = a[i] + b[i] + carry;

        if(temp>9)
        {
            c[k] = temp % 10;
            carry = temp/10;

        }
        else
        {
            c[k] = temp;
            carry = 0;
        }
        k++;
    }

    while(i<*an)
    {
        temp = carry + a[i];
        if(temp>9)
        {
            c[k] = temp % 10;
            carry = temp/10;

        }
        else
        {
            c[k] = temp;
            carry = 0;
        }
        k++;i++;
    }

    while(i<*bn)
    {
        temp = carry + b[i];
        if(temp>9)
        {
            c[k] = temp % 10;
            carry = temp/10;

        }
        else
        {
            c[k] = temp;
            carry = 0;
        }
        k++;i++;
    }
    if(carry!=0)
    {
        c[k++] = carry;
    }

    *cn = k;




}

int fibo( int **a, int **b, int **c, int n)
{
    int i, j,*tmpdb;

    int bn = 1, an = 1, cn = 0, bsn = 0, temp;
    int bsquare[100] = {0};

    for(i = 3; i<= n; i++)
        {   
            for(j = 0; j<bn; j++)
                bsquare[j] = *b[j];

            bsn = bn;

            sqr(bsquare,&bsn);
            sum(*a,bsquare,*c,&an,&bsn,&cn);

            tmpdb = *a;
            *a = *b;
            *b = *c;
            *c = tmpdb;

            temp = an;
            an = bn;
            bn = cn;
            cn = temp;



        }
    return bn;

}
```

Comment: `*b[j]` --> `(*b)[j]`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  I can't see the difference between the two, can you give some insight. Also is there some reference on how pointers actually work. I have a lot of doubts in this matter.

Comment: See [DEMO](http://ideone.com/bxmK5W)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in comments by BLUEPIXY, `*b[j]` should be changed to `(*b)[j]`, as you have passed b to `fibo`  as double pointer, b stores address of pointer variable from main function which in turn stores address where array is present.

`*b[j]` will get evaluated to `*(*(b+j))` address stored in b is valid(address of pointer variable b from main), `b+j` takes you to invalid address, accessing it might be leading to segment fault

You need j'th element from array whose address is stored in b, right way to access will be  `(*b)[j]` where (*b) gets you the base address of your array

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating `b[]` value as you are expecting it to be. you have stored `b[0]=t2` and after that it is not updated anywhere else. so your program gives segmentation fault at `b[1]`.So i will say just update `b[]` array and you are good to go. and also please practice to provide a little bit of comment in your code it is really hard to read.

Comment: b gets swapped with c after every iteration in fibo()